# Sony, Camera: interface

Tags: camera, sony

Good Evening,
  I'm starting the develop of an App with the Action Cam FDR-X1000, and I have 2 questions about the capabilities of the system:
- can I manage the camera (using Camera Remote API) by the usb interface instead the Wifi?
- using the wifi interface, if I'm operating with the camera by, for example, a smartwatch, can I connect a smartphone to the same camera and send commands to retreive stored images, etc?

Thank you for the attention

Andrea Carapezzi

Comment: Did you search on any documentation or support? Have you research about it?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions.

1. You will not be able to communicate with the camera using the camera API over usb
2. You will be able to connect your camera to a smartphone and get images from the camera using the camera remote API. You can visit the Camera remote API landing page to find out more: https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. About question 2, I'd like to know if I can connect a smartphone and the smartwatch in the same moment?

Comment: Yes you absolutely can.